# How to cut a few seconds out of movie file?

Tags: windows, command-line, video-editing

I have a lot of movies that have only a few seconds of interesting material. I would like to write some script to do it (batch script?).

what kind of tool has a good command line interface to do thing like that?

Comment: I added the command-line tag.  BTW.. This isn't what you're looking for 'cos it's just mp3. But I did see a program called mp3splt. command line  usage is-   mp3splt song.mp3 10.12 14.25 -o out.mp3 [Split song.mp3 starting at 
10min 12sec, ending at 14mins 25sec and save the mp3 slice in a new 
file called out.mp3]    Something like that for movies would be ideal for you.

Comment: @Barlop: Yeah, but if you want different parts in EVERY file ... that is quite inconvenient with a cli tool. IMHO. (For Audio, I use Audacity.)

Comment: @Shiki  He said command line interface. And if you know what parts you want then how is it inconvenient?  you type in the 2 times.. as oppose to a GUI of selecting.  I wouldn't say either is inconvenient, though GUI could be less convenient in certain situations. And by the way. That mp3splt program uses a lot less RAM than audacity, and audacity i think has to convert the whole thing to a WAV. That mp3splt type of program for movies would be what he's looking for, based on his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be real hard / inconvenient to do that with a CLI tool.
Just use "[AviDemux2](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)" or you can record a piece from the movie with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) too.

Comment: From what he's said clearly it'd not be hard or inconvenient with a CLI tool(which he sensibly specified/asked about). It -may- be inconvenient with a GUI, especially the suggestion of recording each piece individually.  I suppose if you had some automatic way involving the GUI then that may be useful to him, but you show no sign of that in your answer.

Comment: it looks very cool, the command line interface doesnt look that bad, but i will see. thx!

Comment: Your answer suggests that your solution isn't CLI. But as IAdaptor has suggested, it has a CLI. Good to know if it's useful..

Comment: I know it has a CLI tool, but it still doesn't make sense, unless you write a whole text file with full of exact times, config options and stuff and have the CLI run on them all. Oh well.

Comment: it could just be 1 command that one needs to be executed on a set of files. if each file needs the same few seconds removed. or just copy/pasting the command and changing the times and filenames it executes on. The files may even be named file1 file2 file3, so possible to generate them. CLI is not pointless and can be quicker than a GUI.